# How to get counts of characters on every line in TextView?

Tags: android, textview

My `TextView` has multi-line text. And I want to get counts of characters every single line. I have tried `String.split("\n")`, but it didn't work...

Comment: How many lines are there in your TextView?

Comment: the textview has six line.

Answer (score 1):

Try to splite by line using below code

```
String lines[] = String.split("\\r?\\n");
```

OR

```
String lines[] = String.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

and If you don’t want empty lines:

```
String lines[] = String.split("[\\r\\n]+")
```

Comment: make edittext multiple line by providing android:minLines="6", android:maxLines="10", android:lines="8" in xml code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] lines = String.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
int[] counts = new int[lines.length];
for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++ ){
    String line= lines[i].replace(" ", "").trim();
    counts[i] = line.toCharArray().length;
}
```

Then you will get every line's counts of character even you just have one line or empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function which store each line in different String variable and then count that string length.